# I have a column with datatype nvarchar and I want to sort it in ascending order. How do I achieve it in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

This is what I'm getting

- abc 1
- abc 12
- abc 15
- abc 2
- abc 3

And this is how I want

- abc 1
- abc 2
- abc 3
- abc 12
- abc 15

Query that I use:

```
select *
from view_abc
order by col1
```

Comment: Can you include your query?

Comment: How do you achieve the results above? Is it stored like that in the column, or are you using a query to get the output?

Comment: Actually I'm getting data from View. Query is like this -> select * from view_abc order by col1.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function to strip out the non numeric characters and leave just the value. Use another function to strip out all the numeric data. You can then sort on the two returned values.

It seems like a bit of work at first but once the functions are in you can re-use them in the future. Here's two functions I use regularly when we get data in from external sources and it's not very normalised.

*They may not be the most efficient functions in the world but they work for my purposes*

**1st a function to just leave the numeric portion.**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[StripToAlpha]
(
@inputString nvarchar(4000)
)  
RETURNS varchar(4000)
AS  
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @Counter as int
    DECLARE @strReturnVal varchar(4000)
    DECLARE @Len as int
    DECLARE @ASCII as int

    SET @Counter=0  
    SET @Len=LEN(@inputString)

    SET @strReturnVal = ''

    WHILE @Counter<=@Len
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter = @Counter +1

        SET @ascii= ASCII(SUBSTRING(@inputString,@counter,1))

        IF(@ascii BETWEEN 65 AND 90) OR (@ascii BETWEEN 97 AND 122) 
        BEGIN
            SET @strReturnVal = @strReturnVal + (SUBSTRING(@inputString,@counter,1))
        END
    END

    RETURN @strReturnVal

END
```

**2nd a function to extract the value from a text field**, *this also handle percentages (e.g. abc 23% comes out as 0.23) but this is not required in your case.*

You'll need to CREATE an 'fn' schema of change the schema name first...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[ConvertToValue]
(
@inputString nvarchar(4000)
)  
RETURNS Float
AS  
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @Counter as int
    DECLARE @strReturnVal varchar(4000)
    DECLARE @ReturnVal Float
    DECLARE @Len as int
    DECLARE @ASCII as int

    SET @Counter=0  
    SET @Len=LEN(@inputString)

    SET @strReturnVal = ''

    IF @inputString IS NULL
        BEGIN
            Return NULL
        END

    IF @Len = 0 OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@inputString))) = 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnVal=0
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            WHILE @Counter<=@Len
            BEGIN
                SET @Counter = @Counter +1

                SET @ascii= ASCII(SUBSTRING(@inputString,@counter,1))

                IF(@ascii BETWEEN 48 AND 57) OR (@ascii IN (46,37)) 
                BEGIN
                    SET @strReturnVal = @strReturnVal + (SUBSTRING(@inputString,@counter,1))
                END
            END

            if RIGHT(@strReturnVal,1)='%'
                BEGIN
                    SET @strReturnVal = LEFT(@strReturnVal,len(@strReturnVal)-1)
                    SET @strReturnVal = CAST((CAST(@strReturnVal AS FLOAT)/100) AS nvarchar(4000))
                END

            SET @ReturnVal = ISNULL(@strReturnVal,0)
        END

    RETURN @ReturnVal

END
```

Now we have the two functions created you can simply do

```
SELECT * 
FROM view_abc
ORDER BY fn.StripToAlpha(Col1), fn.ConvertToValue(Col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Edited :

```
SELECT  CAST(SUBSTRING(ColumnNameToOrder,  CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnNameToOrder, 0), LEN (ColumnNameToOrder)) AS INT) AS IntColumn,   SUBSTRING(ColumnNameToOrder,0,  CHARINDEX(' ',  ColumnNameToOrder, 0)) AS CharColumn, * FROM view_abc ORDER BY Charcolumn, Intcolumn
```

Instead of ColumnNameToOrder, you can put your column name which contains the data like 'abc 123'...
Tell me if it works please.

Comment: Can u tell what should I add in place of 'abc 123'?

Comment: The name of your column which contains the data that you want to order by

Comment: and you should Change FROM Users to FROM Your table name

Comment: Can you post your complete query please ? I will edit it for you.

Comment: Ya. I did that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with. Maybe it can help you, or at least point you in the right direction.

I tested the values. When the values have a **zero**, the order is like you would like the order to be. Like this:

- abc 01
- abc 02
- abc 03
- abc 12
- abc 15

So you can run this query to update the existing values, to add the **zero**.

```
UPDATE abc
SET col1 = 'abc 0' + SUBSTRING(col1, 5, 1)
WHERE LEN(col1) = 5
```

Or you can do the above query like this if the first three characters can vary:

```
UPDATE abc
SET col1 = (SUBSTRING(col1, 1, 3) + ' 0' + SUBSTRING(col1, 5, 1))
WHERE col1 LIKE 'abc__'
```

This will override the existing value in the col1 column, only when the length of the current String is of length 5.

Then you can run the following query to get the results:

```
SELECT col1
FROM abc
ORDER BY col1 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=cint(right(Fields!Col1.Value, instrrev(Fields!Col1.Value, " ")-1))
```

This will work in SSRS and sort correctly, but will only work if Col1 always contains a space, and that the characters after the space can be converted to an integer.